# Embed D3.js with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, d3.js

I'm trying to create an iframe from JavaScript and embed D3 with in the iframe.like this

```
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'block';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
    var target = document.getElementById("pp12");     

    var container=d3.select("#block").append("svg")
                  .attr("width", 200)
                  .attr("height", 200)
                  .style("border", "1px solid black");

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(iDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    console.log('iframe.contentWindow =', iframe.contentWindow);
    target.appendChild(iframe);
```

But i couldn't do. kindly help me.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MaheshJayachandran/v9d8hcav/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...
Do it this way

```
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(iDiv.outerHTML);
```

fiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8xr8ub8s/1/

Comment: I have render a circle inside iframe and i have trigger mouse over event. MouseOver is working outside the iframe but inside iframe its not working.

Comment: The problem is that circle in the fiddle is not attached to any JS.
I mean in the frame only the HTML has got encoded and gone.
The listeners need to be attached to the circle with in the iframe.

Comment: I have provide a fiddle.Kindy can u tell me how to attach listeners  to the circle with in the iframe.